# Units conversion - quanta/cm$^2$/s and photons/cm$^2$/s

Tags: units, unit-conversion

Can you tell me if there is any difference between these 2 units?

$\log \mathrm{quanta/cm^2/s}$ vs $\log \mathrm{photons/cm^2/s}$

Thanks

Comment: Photons are a type of quantua. So the latter is more vague/general.

Answer (score 0):

"Number of photons" and "Number of quanta" are both dimensionless so

"quanta" cm$^{-2}$ s$^{-1}$ has the same units as "photons" cm$^{-2}$ s$^{-1}$.

But strictly, both expressions are wrong since:

$\log{x}= (x-1) - (1/2)(x-1)^2 + (1/3)(x-1)^3 - (1/4)(x-1)^4 + ...$

So the argument inside the logarithm should be unit-less.

Comment: Note that $\log(a/b)\equiv\log(a)-\log(b)$, so it is possible for units to be present in the argument of logarithms, though care needs to be taken (I believe there is a PSE post on the use of units in log)

Comment: Relevant posts on why and how logarithms of dimensionful quantities can be made to work: [Why is it “bad taste” to have a dimensional quantity in the argument of a logarithm or exponential function?](/q/364771), [What is the logarithm of a kilometer? Is it a dimensionless number?](/q/13060), and links therein.